# Surface View Camera Preview

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

Having a little trouble getting my `SurfaceView` to show my camera preview. I've looked at some questions on here and Google'd some tuts but I think it may be a small error on my end that I'm just not seeing.

**Code**

```
public class RoofPitchActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    ...
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_roof_pitch);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        ...         

        Preview preview = new Preview(this);
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        preview.setCamera(mCamera);
    }

    ...
    ...

    class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        public Preview(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
            mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
            addView(mSurfaceView);

            mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        }

        public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
            if (mCamera == camera) {
                return;
            }

            stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();

            mCamera = camera;

            if (mCamera != null) {
                requestLayout();

                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        }

        private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight());
            requestLayout();
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        }    
    }
}
```

So when the activity is launched the `SurfaceView` is black. The camera does not appear to be rendering the preview onto the `SurfaceView`. I'm sure there's something small I'm missing, or maybe it's just a fundemental misunderstanding of how this works. A fresh set of eyes with a little explanation would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the SurfaceView is visible through the layout?  It appears behind everything else.  (Try commenting out the camera code, and just fill the Surface with red using Canvas.)  You'll have some problems with your current handling of Camera -- you really want it tied to the Activity lifecycle, not the Surface lifecycle.  Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) has a few examples; see e.g. Continuous Capture.  A discussion can be found at https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to my question ended up being device specific. The code was acceptable but my device I'm using to debug is a Nexus 7. This means the camera is front facing and the normal call to the camera does not work. An interesting and funny read about this can be found [**in this article**](http://www.plattysoft.com/2014/03/07/android-front-cameras-cameras/)

```
Camera.open();
```

does not work. You must use

```
Camera.open(0);
```

So my code ended up with a conditional check for the camera and now it works fine.

Like so

```
public void setCamera() {
        stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean backCamera = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
        boolean frontCamera = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT);

        if (frontCamera) {
            mCamera = Camera.open(0);
        } else if (backCamera) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        }

        if (mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight());
            requestLayout();

            try {
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
}
```